# Exporting specific gridfs files from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have large number of files in database,I need to take backup of specific week files and export to another database.I can dump fs.files based on uploadDate.

`./mongodump --port <port> --db <Database> --collection fs.files --query <json> --out <destination>`

How can I export the specific fs.chunks data while iterating fs.files in the shell?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog post and the gist for a bash script that will do what's asked for here. Run this script from the command line of the mongodb server. It will loop through the fsfiles collection and exporting the files using the mongofiles utility that is included with MongoDB.
[Original Blog Post](http://blog.vladimirm.com/2011/06/export-files-from-mongodb-gridfs-with-directory-paths/)

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/lsm/1056037)